# Connecting to OrientDB from Python (options)

Tags: python, orientdb, pyorient

So I'm looking at the best solution in terms of "Ease of Learning"
for working on a orientdb database from Python.

options:

- https://github.com/mogui/pyorient  (doesn't support the latest)
- Bulbs though Rexster
- The REST API of Orientdb

Any of you have some experience with the above or knows something better ? Thank you.

Comment: I thought `pyorient` worked just fine with `orientdb` 1.7.10, the latest production version -- what problems are you observing?

Comment: nothing wrong with pyorient, but the latest one (OrientDB 2.0-rc1) has that very nice "Graph" visual tool in the Studio.

Comment: Ah, you want to use the "LATEST DEVELOPMENT RELEASE (not recommended for production)".  I guess that, for experimental purposes, I'd hack something temporary on top of their REST API while waiting for 2.0 to go production-release and then pyorient to support it.

Comment: As of today, the Orientdb that is downloaded by default from their site uses protocol v. 32, while pyorient uses protocol v. 28. I'd say it is unmaintaind to the point of unusability

Comment: pyorient works well unless you are looking to run orientDB in distributed mode. The next release should have support for the binary serializer which will have support for distributed and is much faster.

Answer (score 2):

As of today (Jan 10, 2016), the best way to install the current pyorient (1.4.6a) seems to be:

pip install --pre --upgrade pyorient

This version supports protocol 32 as per 
https://github.com/mogui/pyorient/blob/master/pyorient/constants.py#L8